# gvim menus are too big

Tags: gvim, linux, compile-vim

Many compiler, install module, gyrations later, I was finally able to get vim with the gui to compile and execute.

However, the menus, both at the top of the main screen, and the pull down menus are too big.  Each entry of the pull down menus looks like there are 2-3 CRLF before the text.  This is not what I am used to.
[image: gvim snip]

What is causing this?
What do I have to do during the compile process to repair this?
Is this just a setting issue ?

openSuse 15.4

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! That does look odd. Have you tried comparing with the packages for your OS? Maybe they compile differently than you did and it comes out better?

Comment: It's almost as if there's an issue with line endings in the source, but that doesn't make sense. Where did you get the source?

It might be helpful if you were to list the steps you followed to compile, and the tools you used.

Comment: Which toolkit are you using for gVim? It doesn't look like GTK but one of the old X11 toolkits like Xaw or some such? Posting the full output from `:version` or `vim --version` would help.